# How can I shorten a very long string in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with a PHP breadcrumb function I am using, when the page name is very long, it overflows out of the box, which then looks really ugly.

My question is, how can I achieve this: "This is a very long string" to "This is..." with PHP?

Any other ideas on how I could handle this problem would also be appreciated, thanx in advance!

Here is the breadcrumb function:

```
function breadcrumbs() {
 // Breadcrumb navigation
    if (is_page() && !is_front_page() || is_single() || is_category()) {
        echo '<ul class="breadcrumbs">';
        echo '<li class="front_page"><a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'">'.get_bloginfo('name').'</a> <span style="color: #FFF;">&raquo;</span> </li>';

        if (is_page()) {
            $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);

            if ($ancestors) {
                $ancestors = array_reverse($ancestors);

                foreach ($ancestors as $crumb) {
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($crumb).'">'.get_the_title($crumb).'</a> <span style="color: #FFF;">&raquo;</span> </li>';
                }
            }
        }

        if (is_single()) {
            $category = get_the_category();
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a></li>';
        }

        if (is_category()) {
            $category = get_the_category();
            echo '<li>'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</li>';
        }

        // Current page
        if (is_page() || is_single()) {
            echo '<li class="current">'.get_the_title().'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } elseif (is_front_page()) {
        // Front page
        echo '<ul class="breadcrumbs">';
        echo '<li class="front_page"><a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'">'.get_bloginfo('name').'</a></li>';
        echo '<li class="current">Home Page</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want a more nice (word limited) trucation you can use `explode` to split the string by spaces and then append each word (array entry) until you've reached your max limit

Something like:

```
define("MAX_LEN", 15);
$sentance = "Hello this is a long sentance";
$words = explode(' ', $sentance);
$newStr = "";
foreach($words as $word) {
  if(strlen($newStr." ".$word) >= MAX_LEN) {
     break;
  }
  $newStr = $newStr." ".$word;
}
```

Comment: Similar to how I truncate strings to avoid sub-word cutting.

Comment: @Martin: except the fact your answer given after almost an hour after than this.

Comment: I never questioned time? I added my two pence afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with UTF-8 as charset, I suggest using the [`mb_strimwidth`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php) method as it is multibyte safe and won´t mess up multibyte chars. It also appends a placeholder string like `...` automatically, with `substr` you´d have to do that in an additional step.

Usage sample:

```
echo mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10, "...", "UTF-8"); // .. or some other charset
// outputs Hello W...
```

Comment: +1 for I didn't know about that function! I wrote the exact same myself :)

Answer (score 2):

You can safely use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: ...But this would give partial endings of the last word most times.

Comment: It wasn't declared in the question. I don't like this kind of approach like yours: given a question, given an answer then a commenter coming and downvote every other answers. Nice, man.

Comment: @Martin Bean - Maybe if the OP had specified that partial word endings were out of bounds your comment would be worth something. Stick to the OP request or put a comment to the question for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

and eventually [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) to break long words

Comment: How would that help in a breadcrumb list? Breadcrumbs are traditionally horizontal...

Answer (score 1):

$string    = "This is a very long string";

$newString =  substr( $string, 0, 7)."...";

// Output = This is...

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, it should be done on the client side. You can use CSS/JS for the same.

Set this CSS property: [text-overflow: ellipsis](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html). 
However, it will work only in IE. To use the same in Firefox as well, you can do something like [this](http://www.jide.fr/english/emulate-text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-with-css).

If you do not mind javascript plugins, use one of the [jQuery ellipsis plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/2229).

**Edit:** These methods will work even when dealing with unicode, which can be a bit tricky if you try to handle this using php. (Like substr function)

**Edit 2:** If your problem is just the overflowing text and you do not mind not having the "..." at the end then it is even more simple. Simply, use the CSS: `text-overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate the string at max length and then search for the last space:

**Multibyte safe (Requires PHP > = 4.2)**

```
function mb_TruncateString($string, $length = 40, $marker = "...")
{
    if (mb_strlen($string) <= $length)
        return $string;

    // Trim at given length
    $string = mb_substr($string, 0, $length);

    // Get the text before the last space
    if(mb_ereg("(.*)\s", $string, $matches))
        $string = $matches[1];

    return $string  . $marker;
}
```

**Following is not multibyte safe**

```
function TruncateString($string, $length = 40, $marker = "...")
{
    if (strlen($string) <= $length)
        return $string;

    // Trim at given length
    $string = substr($string, 0, $length);

    // Get the text before the last space
    if(preg_match("/(.*)\s/i", $string, $matches))
        $string = $matches[1];

    return $string  . $marker;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You're after a truncate function. This is what I use:

```
/**
 * @param string $str
 * @param int $length
 * @return string
 */
function truncate($str, $length=100)
{
    $str = substr($str, $length);
    $words = explode(' ', $str); // separate words into an array
    array_pop($words); // discard last item, as 9/10 times it's a partial word
    $str = implode(' ', $words); // re-glue the string
    return $str;
}
```

And usage:

```
echo truncate('This is a very long page name that will eventually be truncated', 15);
```

Comment: 9 times out of 10 is not 10 times out of 10.